# After installing angular-cli getting error on ng -v

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using ubuntu 16 OS and my node and npm versions are as below

node v7.4.0

npm 4.0.5

if i give ng new my-project i am getting below error

> It seems like you're using a project generated using an old version of
>   the Angular CLI. The latest CLI now uses webpack and has a lot of
>   improvements including a simpler workflow, a faster build, and smaller
>   bundles.
>
> To get more info, including a step-by-step guide to upgrade the CLI,
>   follow this link:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14

Please help me on this

Comment: It seems the folder in which you are executing `ng new my-project` has other files e.g. package.json etc. Execute it in a folder that does not have any other files (no problems if there are folders, but not with the same name as your new project).

Comment: i have created new empty folder and tried i am getting the same error. But in /etc/ folder or in /opt/* folders i am able to run ng -v.

Comment: Did you have previous version of `angular-cli` installed? If yes, did you uninstall it before installing latest version?

Comment: yes i have unistalled angular-cl, then cleared npm cache then again installed it.

Comment: OK... try this.... uninstall `angular-cli`... clean npm cache... delete folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli` (or folder *angular-cli* from your global npm_modules folder). Reinstall angular-cli and try creating new project.

Comment: It worked for me now! You can add answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do following steps:

- Uninstall `anguar-cli` and clean npm cache by executing the following:

  `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`

  `npm cache clean`
- Delete folder */usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli* (or folder angular-cli
  from your global `npm_modules` folder).
- Reinstall angular-cli using `npm install -g angular-cli@latest` and then try
  creating new project.